# Ограничение вывода

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите как вывести только 6 уровней?

```
<?php
$sql= "SELECT id, parent_id, user_id FROM modxev_programm_one group by `id` asc";
$cats = array();
$statement = $modx->query($sql);
$parent = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($parent as $res) {
    $cats[$res['parent_id']][] =  $res;
}
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id){
    global $modx;
    if(is_array($cats) and count($cats[$parent_id])>0){
        $tree = '<div class="item-children">';
        $count = 0;
         foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
            $count = $count + 1;
            $coountt = $cat['parent_id'];
            if ($us = $modx->getObject('modUser', $cat['user_id'])){
                $login = $us->get('username');
            }
            if ($us = $modx->getObject('modUserProfile', $cat['user_id'])){
                $fio = $us->get('fullname');
                $skype = $us->get('skype');
                $phone = $us->get('phone');
                $mail = $us->get('email');
                if ($us->get('photo')){
                    $photo = $us->get('photo');
                }else $photo='assets/img/noimg.jpg';
            }
            $tree .= '<div class="item-child">
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="item-parent">';
            $tree .= '<div class="item-data" data-fio="'.$fio.'" data-skype="'.$skype.'" data-mail="'.$mail.'" data-phone="'.$phone.'"  data-photo="'.$photo.'">
                            <img src="'.$photo.'" alt="'.$login.'">
                            <div class="span">'.$login.' - '.$count.'</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
            $tree .= '
                </div>
            </div>
            ';         
         }
         $tree .= '</div>';
     } 
     else return 'none';
     return $tree; 
}
$sqlu= "SELECT id FROM modxev_programm_one where user_id=".$modx->user->get('id')."";
$st = $modx->query($sqlu);
$pr = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($pr as $row) {
    echo build_tree($cats,$row['id']);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так уж конкретно не скажешь, но наводку дать можно:

```
echo build_tree($cats,$row['id']);
```

Добавляем третий параметр, указывающий уровень

```
echo build_tree($cats,$row['id'],1);
```

Теперь функция:

```
function build_tree($cats,$parent_id, $lvl){
    if ($lvl > 6) { return '' };
    global $modx;
    ...
```

И изменяем рекурсивный вывод:

```
$tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id'],($lvl+1));
```

Comment: а как дописывать недостающие блоки, например возле valli78 справа пусто, а нужно записать справа например "пусто"

Comment: @Aslero К сожалению, но это уже другой вопрос, другое решение, другие ответы.

Comment: сейчас пересоздам вопрос) спасибо